# How to ignore moved lines in a diff

Tags: diff

I am currently working on a source code generation tool. To make sure that my changes do no introduce any new bugs, a `diff` between the output of the program before and after my changes would theoretically be a valuable tool.

However, this turns out to be harder than one might think, because the tool outputs lines where the order does not matter (like `import` statements, function declarations, …) in a semi-randomly ordered way. Because of this, the output of `diff` is cluttered with many changes that are in fact only lines moved to another position in the same file.

Is there a way to make diff ignore these moves and only output the lines that have really been added or removed?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to change your tool to generate functions and import declarations in a specific (e.g. lexicographical, if possible in your language) order?

Comment: @Daniel Beck: See my comment to Gilles' answer below.

Comment: Old subject, but to summarize comments below, how would this `diff` tool be able to separate valid moves from invalid ones, as Order of instructions in code _does_ matter, and cases where this is not true are limited (imports, declaration of functions and classes, etc.) ?

Comment: @Joël: The answer is simply that I knew that the generator changes I had to test would not introduce any bugs related to changing the order of lines. Of course, you need an tool based on a parser for the target language to avoid false-positives in the general case (or simply a comprehensive test suite for your generator), but this was supposed to be a quick one-off check in addition to code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a simple diff, store the result somewhere (to avoid another diff), loop through the lines in either version, then remove those from the other side.

This spawned a [separate project](https://github.com/l0b0/diff-ignore-moved-lines) for the working code. [The code.](https://github.com/l0b0/diff-ignore-moved-lines/blob/master/diff-ignore-moved-lines.sh)

Comment: I'm not sure what that's supposed to do exactly, but it doesn't seem to produce the wanted results. As I understand the question, from the two examples in the code `/tmp/old` and `/tmp/new` no diff results would be wanted since there's just lines that have been moved around. This code however does produce results.

Comment: Fixed the code.

Comment: Haven't tested the answer as I finished the merging process mentioned above a long time ago, but from a glance at the code it looks as if it could work.

Answer (score 9):

You may try to sort'em first. Something like:

```
sort file-a > s-file-a
sort file-b > s-file-b
diff s-file-a s-file-b
```

Bash (and zsh) can do this in one line with [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

```
diff <(sort file-a) <(sort file-b)
```

Comment: This might be an option, but the generated diffs would not be very useful then, because I would lose all the line number and context information…

Comment: Even if I am still hoping for a better solution, I went with this approach for verifying the batch of changes I had been working on.

Comment: I can foresee where this would miss some changes. Sometimes order matters, sometimes it doesn't. You discard all context.

Comment: For an ordering refactor where I wanted to make sure everything that did exist still does, this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is structured into sections, it is just the sections that are out of order, and there exists a regular expression that you can use to recognize the section header, you could [csplit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csplit) the files into their sections and then compare the sections pairwise.

For instance, I just did this on two MySQL dumps to compare them after some of the database names had changed case (and therefore the dump listed them in a different order):

```
csplit all-07sep2015-11:19:12.sql '/Current Database/-1' '{*}'  # split the dump made before the change, creating files xx00, xx01, ...
csplit -f yy all-07sep2015-12:26:12.sql '/Current Database/-1' '{*}' # split the dump made after the change, creating files yy00, yy01, ...
fgrep 'Current Database' xx?? yy?? | perl -lne 'BEGIN{my %foo}; /(^....).*`(.*)`/ and push(@{$foo{lc($2)}}, $1); END {printf("diff -di %s %s\n", @{$_}) for values %foo}' | sh -x | less  # match the pairs and compare them with diff
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have control over the tool. Then make its output predictable: instead of emitting declarations in a semi-random order, use (say) alphabetical order as a last resort. This will not only have the benefit of removing useless cruft from diffs, but also of making the tool's output easier to read and verify for a human being.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer does not help me at all – if it was so easy, I would change it right away. Furthermore, I am currently merging changes from a project the generator was originally forked from, so adding such a rather far-reaching change would complicate that process even more…